# Integrating passport-github and node-github

Tags: node.js, authentication, github, passport.js

I'm using passport-github to allow users to authenticate in my app using Github OAuth. I save the access token to DB so I can use it later.

Now I'm trying to use [node-github](https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github) to make some API calls, but there is no way I can get it to authenticate. User and password authentication is not an option, since I'm trying to avoid the user having to authenticate every time, and the other methods (there are four auth methods according to the README) do not work (or at least I'm unable to make them work).

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
exports.create = function( req, res ) {

var project = new Project( req.body );
project.user = req.user;

var token = req.user.providerData.refreshToken.access_token; //Token gotten from passport-github

var GitHubApi = require( 'github' );

var github = new GitHubApi( {
    // required
    version:    '3.0.0',
    // optional
    debug:      true,
    protocol:   'https',
    pathPrefix: '/api/v3', // for some GHEs
    timeout:    5000
} );

github.authenticate( {
    type:  'oauth',
    token: token
} );

github.repos.create(
    {
        headers:     {},
        name:        project.githubRepoUrl,
        description: project.description,
        private:     project.isPrivate,
        auto_init:   true
    },
    function( err, res ) {
        if( err ) {
            console.log( err );
        }

        if( res ) {
            console.log( 'Created repo with id: ' + res.id + 'and name: ' + res.name )
        }
    }
);
```

Relevant console output:

```
REQUEST:  { host: 'api.github.com',
port: 443,
path: '/api/v3/user/repos?access_token=3488bfe013e9c071f9af5a45bda8f8bcd23c7d5a',
method: 'post',
headers: 
   { host: 'api.github.com',
     'content-length': 72,
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'user-agent': 'NodeJS HTTP Client',
     accept: 'application/vnd.github.beta+json' } }
REQUEST BODY: {"name":"sdfdsf","description":"dsfds","private":false,"auto_init":true}

STATUS: 401
HEADERS: {"server":"GitHub.com","date":"Sun, 03 Aug 2014 04:22:04 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","status":"401 Unauthorized","x-github-media-type":"github.beta; format=json","x-ratelimit-limit":"60","x-ratelimit-remaining":"59","x-ratelimit-reset":"1407043324","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","x-frame-options":"deny","content-security-policy":"default-src 'none'","content-length":"83","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-expose-headers":"ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval","access-control-allow-origin":"*","x-github-request-id":"40E45687:2B9A:596F677:53DDB8EC","strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains","x-content-type-options":"nosniff"}
[error] { [Error: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}]
[error]   message: '{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}',
[error]   code: 401 } null undefined
{ [Error: {"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}]
message: '{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}',
code: 401 }
```

Does someone have done this before? Is there any tutorial on this?

Comment: The oauth method should work though (https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github#authentication) if you have created an token for that repo (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use)

Comment: Hi @VonC, I'm creating the repo on behalf of the user, and I don't have access to the users tokens. What I'm trying to do is to autheticate with GitHub using OAuth so that I can act on behalf of the user.

Comment: "act on behalf of the user." You need to get a token from that user, then.

Comment: Yep, but that I do through passport-github already. I explain it in the question.

Comment: Then what exactly is that "other method" which isn't working? What exact error message do you get?

Comment: It is using that token (obtained through passport-github) with node-github that I cannot do.

Comment: I'll put some code...

Comment: Ok, what is the error message you get?

Comment: I put it on the question for more clarity.

Comment: Maybe the scope of that token (https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) doesn't allow for creating new repo?

Comment: This are the scopes i requested in when obtaining the token: ['user', 'repo', 'delete_repo', 'admin:repo_hook']

Comment: I just revoked the token and went through the OAuth flow again, and though the scopes are the ones I expect, the results are the same.

Comment: Do you mind moving the conversation [into the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58561/discussion-between-reydelleon-and-vonc)?